# How to get javascript variable to php

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to get the javascript variable value to php.

here is my javascript code:

```
function getResults()
{
var radios = document.getElementsByName("address");    
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
{       
if (radios[i].checked) {
var a = radios[i].value
alert(a);
break;
}
}
}
```

from this javascript i want to get variable a's value inside php code onclick on submit button.
how can i do this?

i tried this

```
$var1 = $_GET["a"];
```

Comment: Check out AJAX tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Do this..

```
   $var1 = <?=$_GET["a"]?>;
```

to communicate a value from JavaScript to PHP do following

```
$var1 = <?=$_POST["a"]?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is almost correct:

```
var a = <?=$_GET["a"]?>;
```

Comment: Seems to me OP wants to know how to get JS variables to PHP, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript code runs on client-side, but PHP is server-side code, you need to send your JS variables to the server. You can do this using AJAX.

Hint: AJAX calls usually use POST instead of GET.

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
 $var1 = $_GET["a"];
```

on:

```
 $var1 = <?=$_POST["a"]?>;
```

Comment: The goal seems to be to communicate a value from JavaScript to PHP, not the other way around.